# Why do I need to call the upgrade_account in the balance pallet?

Tags: balances, upgrade, storage-migration

With the introduction of version 0.9.42, the logic of how [balances work](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12951) in Substrate changed. This version upgrade introduced a new extrinsic called `upgrade_account`. The `fee_frozen` attribute of the `AccountData` is then used as an `ExtraFlag`, indicating whether the account is upgraded or not. I do not see why this extra flag is important, as it is not used anywhere in the pallet.

I couldn't find any resources related to the question of why upgrading an account is critical. It is only mentioned that this upgrade should be done.

If it is obvious, then I am sorry for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

The upgrade of an account happens automatically when it is accessed. So in theory - nothing is needed to be done on your sode.
But to aid the process and have an eager migration, it is possible to call `upgrade_account` for all accounts with the provided [script](https://github.com/ggwpez/substrate-scripts/blob/master/upgrade-accounts.py). Then all accounts will be upgraded had have the `ExtraFlag` set.
The `ExtraFlag` prevents an account from being upgraded twice. When we add more features in the future, we can also use that flag to indicate whether an account already supports that feature or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm eager to see potential use cases for the migrated accounts.